# How to pass input variable in structure directive?

Tags: angular

There is a structure directive:

```
 @Directive({
        selector: '[loading]',
    })
    export class LoadingDirective {
        loadingFactory: ComponentFactory<LoadingComponent>;
        loadingComponent: ComponentRef<LoadingComponent>;

        @Input()
        set loading(loading: boolean) {}
        @Input('loadingSize') size: number;
    
    }
```

I have tried to pass size:

```
<span *loading="true size=20"></span>
```

Comment: Also I tried this: `*loading="true" *size="20"`

Comment: try [loading]="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span [loading]="true" [loadingSize]="20"></span>
```

Each input property stands on its own, and the `*` is not necessary

**EDIT**

change

```
        @Input()
        set loading(loading: boolean) {}
```

to

```
@Input() loading: boolean;
```

otherwise you are not doing anything with the value, since your setter function is empty

Comment: Could I pass async value like this? `[loading]="customizedLoading$ | async"`?